# Trying to create proportions of churning rates based on only sex. Can get proportions of the total number of members

Tags: r

#### 1. Read the file

```
library(tidyverse)
churnData <- as_tibble(read.table("WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv",
             sep=",",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

#### 2. How many cases of churning and no churning?

```
 churnData %>%
   group_by(Churn) %>% 
   summarise(Count=n())
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Churn Count
  <chr> <int>
1 No     5174
2 Yes    1869
```

#### 3. Determine the number and the proportion of Females and Males in the file

```
 churnData %>%
   group_by(gender) %>%
   summarise(Count=n(),Proportion=Count/nrow(churnData))
 
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gender Count Proportion
  <chr>  <int>      <dbl>
1 Female  3488      0.495
2 Male    3555      0.505
```

#### 4. Given the customer's sex, what is the likelihood of churning?

```
   churnData   %>%
   group_by(gender,Churn)   %>%
   summarise(Count=n(),Proportion=Count/nrow(churnData))

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'gender' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   gender [2]
  gender Churn Count Proportion
  <chr>  <chr> <int>      <dbl>
1 Female No     2549      0.362
2 Female Yes     939      0.133
3 Male   No     2625      0.373
4 Male   Yes     930      0.132
>     summarise(Count=n(),Proportion=Count/nrow[churnData$gender==gender])
Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

need for the Proportions to be:

```
0.731
0.269
0.738
0.262
```

Comment: Do you understand what calculation you need to make? You can't use the whole `nrow(churnData)` as the denominator, you need your gender counts from #3 to be the denominator. So you should save or recreate those counts, not just view them and move on.

Comment: ok i'm trying to create the counts with the mutate so they will be saved for the summarize  genderTable <- table(churnData$gender)
     if (churnData$gender == 'Female')  {
       churnData_gentotal <- mutate(.data=churnData,gentotal=genderTable[1])  }
     else      {  
       churnData_gentotal <- mutate(.data=churnData,gentotal=genderTable[2])  } %>%    I got the Female part to work but r is saying 'unexpected else'   sorry if this is a dumb question but i don't see anything wrong with this.  please help